# QThread Destruction on closing

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, qthread

hello guys I have a worker thread in qt with C++ , if I use `workerThreadPointer->quit();` in mainwindow destruction `~mainwindow{}` or in workerthread destruction its self when I close the program I get this error `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running` but if I use `workerThreadPointer->terminate();` I wont get any errors but `terminate()` method is not recommended so how can I use `quite` on the closing of program with out crashing and getting erorrs

I actually used this and it worked but is it the best way ??

```
bool asghar;
workerThread::workerThread(){
}
workerThread::~workerThread(){
    quit();
    requestInterruption();
    asghar=0;
    wait(100);
}

void workerThread::run(){
   asghar=1;
   while(asghar==true){
   do something
}
}
```

which is basically I force it to gets out of the while loop with a boolian variable but Im not sure its the best option btw if I change that 100 in wait to 10 , its not ganna work.

Comment: changing `wait(100)` to `wait()` is probably all you need? (assuming `asghar` is atomic)

Comment: @AlanBirtles hello and tnx for your comment if I do that the program will never return0 and the thread wont close (atleast I waited 1 or 2 minutes for that)

Comment: difficult to help without a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's a typo because you only wrote pseduo-code or if it's actually like this in your program.  But `while(asgar=true)` doesn't do what you think it does.  The classic `=` vs `==` bug.

```
void workerThread::run(){
   asghar=1;
   while(asghar=true){      // bug
   do something
}
```

Should be this:

```
void workerThread::run(){
   asghar=1;
   while(asghar == true) {  // fixed
   do something
}
```

Also the  compiler is free to optimize away the check to `asghar` since its access is not thread safe.  Consider changing `asghar` to be of type `std::atomic<bool>` or wrap the assignment and check calls with a mutex.

Add print/log statement around the assignment and comparison checks to `asghar` to see what's going on.

Comment: that was a type mistake and had nothing to do with the problem anyway tnx

Comment: @ApAp note that aside from the typo, the issue of making `asghar` access thread-safe is very important. Without it _"the compiler is free to optimize away the check"_ - as selbie wrote.

Comment: It's also possible that `do something` is doing something that takes a really long time. In which case, it needs to also be checking the exit variable (asghar) or have some way by which the destructor to get it out of whatever its blocked on.